# Uploading nested JSON objects to Solr

Tags: json, solr, upload, nested

I'm trying to send my inline JSON file to my Solr Database, but I'm having a problem with my nested objects.

I have two nested objects inside my `_source` object which are `media_gallery` and `stock`. Before my upload used to crash, but I managed to upload it after a few corrections, but my `media_gallery` and `stock` are added as separate objects therefore instead of having the original 1000 objects I get 3000 objects in my Solr DB after my upload.

I'm currently using this command to upload my JSON file:

```
curl 'http://192.168.99.100:8983/solr/gettingstarted/update/json/docs?split=/_source/media_gallery|/_source/stock&commit=true' \
     --data-binary @catalog.json \
     -H 'Content-type:application/json'
```

Basically I'm uploading the file `catalog.json` to `http://192.168.99.100:8983/solr/gettingstarted`.

My `media_gallery` and `stock` are both objects inside an object named `_source` and they're getting split as separate ones.

Could anyone help me with this? I need my `media_gallery` and `stock` objects to be uploaded as objects inside my source object one and not as a few separate ones.

Thank you.

**Solution:**

Basically there was no need for splitting the nested objects. Since i'm uploading everything as a single Solr document therefor i can use the the path `"/"`.

```
curl 'http://192.168.99.100:8983/solr/gettingstarted/update/json/docs?split=&commit=true' --data-binary @catalog.json -H 'Content-type:application/json'
```

Comment: So is the goal to remove the `_source` part of the hierarchy? When you want to index the whole JSON as a single document, having `/` as the first path to split by is required ("If the entire JSON makes a single solr document, the path must be “/”").

Comment: Hey Mats, I don't want to remove my _source. I want it to become a single document with `media_gallery` and `stock` nested inside. Isn't my path correct? it's already using "/"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your split param (remove **/_source/media_gallery** & **/_source/stock**)

> If the entire JSON makes a **single Solr document**, the path must be
>   **“/”**
>    [Solr Guide: json mapping-parameters](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_4/transforming-and-indexing-custom-json.html#mapping-parameters)

Comment: Could you elaborate more and show the change in the command? I tried a few variations and they all came out with errors..

Comment: @Marius I'm glad that it helped you.